# RDS public access lost when adding public subnet with internet gateway and private subnets with NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Any help would be much appreciated!

Initially we had 3 subnets in our AWS VPC. The VPC has an IGW and one default route table with 2 routes - 1 for internal and 0.0.0.0/0 to IGW. A standard initial VPC setup.

Within the VPC we have an RDS instance, with an RDS proxy, and the DB is set for public access while we develop the solution. The DB is associated with the default VPC SG along with a specific SG that whitelists IP addresses for DB connectivity via the public endpoint.

Also within the VPC we have a Lambda that is using the default VPC security group and the 3 subnets mentioned above.

The Lambda can connect to the RDS proxy, and we can connect to the RDS public endpoint via a whitelisted IP - This is as expected.

The Issue:

Now we need to provide the Lambda with internet access (it needs to connect with RedisLabs). To do this we've added:

- A public subnet (subnet-00245f33edbae3358)
- A NAT on the public subnet
- Created a route table associated with the existing 3 private subnets (subnet-06d1124e, subnet-ba82bce1, subnet-3344b955) with a route of 0.0.0.0/0 -> NAT
- Created a route table associated with the new public subnet (subnet-00245f33edbae3358) with a route of 0.0.0.0/0 -> IGW

With this is place the Lambda can still access the DB via the RDS proxy (expected) and can now access the internet (expected), BUT we lose connection to the DB via the public facing endpoint.

Is there something missing in the configuration that will allow Lambda access to the RDS and internet AND will also allow us access to RDS via the public endpoint? OR do we need an SSH tunnel within the public subnet to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Additional Info:

The RDS currently has the following SG's:
- prod-auth-service-rds - allows TCP 3306 from my whitelisted IP
- sg-11cb746b (default) - All traffic with, self referencing source (sg-11cb746b)

The RDS is on subnets:
- subnet-06d1124e - existing private subnet
- subnet-ba82bce1 - existing private subnet
- subnet-3344b955 - existing private subnet

The NAT is on subnet subnet-00245f33edbae3358

Comment: what is the sg on the RDS allow?  you said previously that you could access the RDS on the public endpoint but you whitelisted an IP... now that the lambda is moved to a different subnet, that SG may need to change to white list the private subnet.... what subnet is the RDS in?

Comment: Thanks JD D - I've updated the question above with additional info section and referenced the SG's and Routes etc. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Reread your response, if your RDS DB is on private subnets, then it can’t be publicly accessible regardless of of what you set as that option in the DB’s settings.
——-

After looking at the additional info, I believe the problem is your security group for the RDS.  It only allows traffic from things in your default security group or your personal whitelisted IP.

Even though the lambda is in your default security group, RDS does see traffic as coming from your Lambda, they see it as coming from the NAT Gataway which doesn’t have and security groups.

You can solve this by adding the EIP of your NAT Gateway as an additional whitelisted IP to your inbound rules of the RDS SG.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution, as recommended by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all I needed to do was create the Lambda in a private subnet(s) separate to the existing RDS subnets. The separate subnet(s) then need a route that forwards 0.0.0.0/0 to NAT.

The Lambda now has outbout internet access and RDS access, while the RDS instance can still be reached via its existing public endpoint.